# Set EXIF geolocation using CameraX

Tags: exif, android-camerax

How do you add **Location** information in the image EXIF using CameraX API. I created my own app using *https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#4*.

I sifted through *https://developer.android.com/training/camerax* and *https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/exifinterface* but did not found any guides.

Answer (score 0):

If you took a picture you override `onImageSaved`. There you can write the exif data to your photo. I only have it in Java, but the princip is the same.

```
 ExifInterface exif = null;
      try {
          exif = new ExifInterface(PhotoPath);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
 exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, "location");
```

The different TAGs you can look up [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface). How to get the location is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android) and if you need more information about how to store the location in exif look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280479/how-to-save-gps-coordinates-in-exif-data-on-android).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the location with the [Metadata.setLocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture.Metadata#setLocation(android.location.Location)) method

```kotlin
   val metadata = Metadata().apply {
            location = Location() // set the location here
        }

        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, System.currentTimeMillis())
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
        }
        val contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
        val outputOptions = OutputFileOptions.Builder(contentResolver, contentUri, contentValues)
            .setMetadata(metadata)
            .build()


        imageCapture.takePicture(outputOptions, mainExecutor, object : OnImageSavedCallback {
            override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: OutputFileResults) {
              Log.d(TAG, "Photo URI ${outputFileResults.savedUri}")
 
            }

            override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error", exception)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I would have like to find :
When using CameraX, EXIF data is automatically set but not GPS EXIF tags because :

- permissions are needed to access location
- there are several ways to get the location and that the different options have a different impact on battery drain so it is good to have control.
- it can take a long time to get GPS location (10s with assisted GPS and up to 10mn not assisted).

Here is the function that I call inside the onImageSaved() callback :

```
fun setCurrentLocationInExif(context: Context, uri : Uri, fusedLocationClient : FusedLocationProviderClient){
    // check location permissions
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        throw(Exception("no location found"))
    }
    else {
        // get location (a new one if older than 60s)
        val locRequest = CurrentLocationRequest.Builder().setMaxUpdateAgeMillis(60000).build()
        fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(locRequest, null)
            .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null. In that case we do not go further
                if (location != null){
                    Log.d(TAG, "latitude=${location.latitude}")
                    Log.d(TAG, "longitude=${location.longitude}")
                    val uriFd = context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "rw")
                    if (uriFd != null) {
                        val uriExif = ExifInterface(uriFd.fileDescriptor)
                        uriExif.setGpsInfo(location)
                        uriExif.saveAttributes()
                        uriFd.close()
                    }
                    else{
                        throw(Exception("Cannot find file for uri=$uri"))
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The call in onImageSaved :

```
override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults){
    setCurrentLocationInExif(requireContext(), output.savedUri!!, fusedLocationClient)
}
```

Where fusedLocationClient is defined in my Main Activity onCreate after a lateinit (you will need to activate Play Services/location services in your gradle.build(app)  :

```
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
```