# Android Exif data not stored in picture file

Tags: java, android, image, exif

I'm trying to insert some location data on an image *generated* inside my application (i.e. it's not a picture taken from device camera):

This's `saveImage` method:

```
public static String saveImage(Context context, ContentResolver contentResolver, Bitmap source,
                                   String title, String description, Location location) {
    File snapshot;
    Uri url;

    try {
        File pictures = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File rpi = new File(pictures, context.getString(R.string.app_name));

        if (!rpi.exists())
            if (!rpi.mkdirs())
                return null;

        snapshot = new File(rpi, title);
        OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(snapshot);
        source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();

        if (location != null)
            georeferenceImage(snapshot, location);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, title);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title);

        if (description != null) {
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description);
        }

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, snapshot.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US).hashCode());
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, snapshot.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
        }

        values.put("_data", snapshot.getAbsolutePath());

        url = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }

    return (url != null) ? url.toString() : null;
}
```

This's `georeferenceImage()` method:

```
private static boolean georeferenceImage(@NonNull final File image_file, @NonNull final Location location) {
    try {
        final ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(image_file.getAbsolutePath());
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, getLat(location));
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, location.getLatitude() < 0 ? "S" : "N");
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, getLon(location));
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, location.getLongitude() < 0 ? "W" : "E");
        //exif.setLatLong(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        //exif.setAltitude(location.getAltitude());
        exif.saveAttributes();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And these are lat & lon formatting methods:

```
private static String getLon(@NonNull final Location location) {
    String[] degMinSec = Location.convert(location.getLongitude(), Location.FORMAT_SECONDS).split(":");
    return degMinSec[0] + "/1," + degMinSec[1] + "/1," + degMinSec[2] + "/1000";
}

private static String getLat(@NonNull final Location location) {
    String[] degMinSec = Location.convert(location.getLatitude(), Location.FORMAT_SECONDS).split(":");
    return degMinSec[0] + "/1," + degMinSec[1] + "/1," + degMinSec[2] + "/1000";
}
```

Once saved I see no position data (I tried with different tools with the same result).
I tried also to use `setLatLon()` and `setAltitude()` methods without luck.
No exceptions are thrown. Inspecting in debug `exif` variable prior `saveAttributes()` call I found only `TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF` and `TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF` but not `TAG_GPS_LATITUDE` and `TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE`.

Comment: What are you messing around with the mediastore and values? You dont need that if you write an exif to file so dont confuse us.

Comment: only to fully depict the running code handling the image ... I don't think this's the case but maybe following lines (mediastore and so on) are wiping exif data for  some reason. Of course the only relevant part of code related to exif handling is `georeferenceImage()` .

Comment: Is the file size different before and after the georeferenceImage() call?

Comment: yes it grows up of 236 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was hiding around getLat() and getLon() formatters.
This's code works better:

```
private static String toExifFmt(double angle) {
    angle = Math.abs(angle);
    final int degree = (int) angle;
    angle *= 60;
    angle -= (degree * 60.0d);
    final int minute = (int) angle;
    angle *= 60;
    angle -= (minute * 60.0d);
    final int second = (int) (angle*1000.0d);

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.setLength(0);
    sb.append(degree);
    sb.append("/1,");
    sb.append(minute);
    sb.append("/1,");
    sb.append(second);
    sb.append("/1000");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280479/how-to-save-gps-coordinates-in-exif-data-on-android/16835626#16835626).